# Get a specific data from URL

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```
{ _id: 5d8b8,
  given_name: 'Abi',
  family_name: 'Abi',
  email: 'AAA@jwt.org',
  password:'password'
 }
```

I have this data and I want to get only email.

```
 const url = 'http://localhost:9098/api/users'

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then(json => setUsers(json.data))
    }, [])
    const getEmail = () => {
        return users.map(user => {
            return (

                <option> {user.email} </option>

            )
        })
    }

<select  onChange={handleAddMessage}
                        value={message.sender}
                        name="sender" id="sender"required>
                    <option>{getEmail()} </option>

                </select>
```

This is how I am trying to do it .I need an easy way to extract email from this data into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the **value** attribute has to be inside the **option** tag.As i can see you are rendering an **option** tag inside an **option** tag because the getEmail is returning a **option** tag:

```
<option>{getEmail()} </option>
```

So the approcach that i came up is to make a method that renders the options based on your list:

```
this.renderEmails = (  ) => {
 let optionList =  users.map(user => {
            return (

                <option value={ user.email }> {user.email} </option>
            )
        })
 return optionList
};
```

And in your render method:

```
<select  onChange={handleAddMessage}
         name="sender" id="sender"required>
       { this.renderEmails() }
</select>
```

Comment: What happened? it should render the list of the emails inside the option tag

Comment: the page is not loading nothing appear

Comment: check this codesandbox this could make you a better idea : https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-night-my4dc

Answer (score 0):

Extract the email when you get the data. Itterate through the data using `forEach` and store it to a variable and finally set it to the users-state

Later you can use `users.map()` to display the email ID

```
const url = 'http://localhost:9098/api/users';

const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then(json => {
        let usersResponse = []; json.data.forEach((data) => {
            usersResponse.push(data.email);
        });
        setUsers(usersResponse)
    })
}, []);


    < select
           onChange = { handleAddMessage }
           value = { message.sender }
           name = "sender" id = "sender" required 
    >
    {
        users.map((email) => {
            <option>{email} </option>
        })
    }
    </select >
```